# How to show all function of exe file

Tags: exe

I have a .exe file and i want to list all function of it. It is possible and have some tool to do it?

P/s: i tried with **IDA** but it is difficult to understand it. Can it resolve my problem?.

Comment: An executable doesn't necessary *have* "functions" at all. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to know what param does this exe accept.

Comment: There is no common way to do this. You'd have to get the program's documentation. Many command line tools also give you help when calling them without any parameters (but I suppose you already tried that)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you must have a very good understanding of Assembly Language, and maybe learning from NASM documentation and the Intel Instruction set will get you to a good level. Before you can continue in this path.

Furthermore, for those who already know little or more Assembly Language, is possible to call the function of an exe, mostly if they are standalone or doesn't depend on any other functions using something like [Asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit). And also you can get this function addresses, and cast them into functions if you know the calling convention used here. For example, __stdcall, __cdecl and others. And if then you know the calling convention, you can use this to construct the function signature, including the return type, usually through the POP, RETURN instruction or the registry that was affected before the function exit, or return to the caller.

You have to find a good debugger, to help you find all this. As you said IDA is good but too complicated, so you can use something like x86dbg, or others like ollyDbg those can help you find the entry point of those functions and use that to construct the signature

so a core like this, assuming that 0x749593 is an address of a a function with maybe takes two argument and return sum.

```
typedef int (*sum)(int first, int second);
Sum mySumFunc;
```

Changing the address of mySumFunc to point to 0x749593, you can call this function `mySumFunc(arg1, arg2 )` and it will still work.